# IPFS nodejs sdk hangs when trying to fetch non existing hash

Tags: node.js, api, ipfs

I have setup nodejs sdk for IPFS, everything is working fine, but when I try to fetch a non existing `hash`, the sdk hangs.

I'm using this package https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api

Here's what my code looks like:

```
const ipfsAPI = require('ipfs-api');

const api = ipfsAPI('/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001');
```

When I try to fetch a valid address using the below code works fine:

```js
api.ls('QmQLXHs7K98JNQdWrBB2cQLJahPhmupbDjRuH1b9ibmwVa')
.then(response => console.log('File retrieved:', response))
.catch(error => console.log('Error while retrieveing file:', error));
```

But when I try to fetch a non existing address, It hangs and doesn't stop.

```js
sdk.sdk.files.get('QmQLXHs7K98JNQdWrBB2cQLJahPhmupbDjRuH1b9ibmwVV')
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try asking here as well: It may be a more mature community in regards to IPFS

https://discuss.ipfs.io/c/help/help-js-ipfs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, here's the url https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/ipfs-nodejs-sdk-hangs-when-trying-to-fetch-non-existing-hash/3920